# How to insert JSONB using SQLAlchemy's 'execute'?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I need to run a function that takes an integer and JSONB data.
In a normal console, I would run it like this:

`select my_func(0, '{"foo": "bar"}'::jsonb)`

This is how I assume it would work in SQLAlchemy:

```
params = {'p1': 0, 'p2': JSONB('{"foo": "bar"}'))}
result = db.engine.execute(text('select my_func(:p1, :p2)'), params)
```

But it does not. How am I supposed to get SQLAlchemy to understand that it is JSONB I am trying to insert?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`JSONB`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB) is for defining column's type, not dealing with values. When using textual SQL and types that require special treatment Python or SQL side use the [`TextClause.bindparams()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause.bindparams) method to provide additional type information:

```
params = { 'p1': 0, 'p2': { "foo": "bar" } }
result = db.engine.execute(
    text('select my_func(:p1, :p2)').bindparams(
        bindparam('p2', type_=JSONB)),
    params)
```

Note that you should pass the dictionary without serializing it yourself. Without using `bindparams()` to provide the type information for SQLAlchemy your bind values are passed to the DB-API cursor pretty much as is when using textual SQL. In that light this should also work:

```
params = {'p1': 0, 'p2': '{"foo": "bar"}'}
result = db.engine.execute(
    text('select my_func(:p1, cast(:p2 as jsonb))'),
    params)
```

The DB-API driver sees a string bind value and handles that as usual. The explicit cast in SQL might also be redundant.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! I realized casting it in the SQL string worked right after I posted this question, and used it as the "workaround". However, the bindparams seems like the official way of doing it so will go with that!